# How to access public folders on iOS with Nativescript?

Tags: ios, nativescript

I am developing a file picker. I handled the Android part but I don't know how to access public folders on iOS. By public folders, I mean the folders where user saves or downloads his files for accessing later. Not the folders private to the application.

How can I access those folders?

Comment: When you say public, do you mean folders outside of your app? If so you should read https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html

Comment: @sbarow It seems that an app cannot access files other than the ones in its sandbox but how does google drive overcomes this? It can open a file viewer and select other files.

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller